# Replace radio buttons with images using JQuery

Tags: jquery, image, radio-button

I have group of radio buttons which I want to replace with images when checked and unchecked.

```
<div id="answerOptions">
<input type="radio" name="answeroption" id="r1" value="radio1" checked=''checked'/>radio1<br/>
<input type="radio" name="answeroption" id="r2" value="radio2"/>radio2<br/>
</div>
```

I have two images 1. button_on.JPG for checked radio button and 2. button_off.JPG for not checked radio button.
I want to accomplish following tasks 
1. I want to replace radio buttons with these images.
2. On load of the page checked radio button should have correct image.

Note: Radio buttons are generated dynamically and their ids as well as value do change on each request.

I need the help using Jquery. Appritiate your inputs.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114166/replacing-radio-buttons-with-different-images), as well as [many helpful results via Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?&q=replace+radio+buttons+image).

Comment: Alex and Yi Jiang- I have already seen this solution, but in the image tick solution mapping of the images are done with the values of the radio buttons which wont help me. Actually question was formatted such a way that it looks duplicate, my mistake. I have updated the question and added one note.

Comment: Hence my *possible* duplicate. Glad to see you've already researched this; sometimes it's good to link to some stuff you've already read to  let us know what doesn't solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use a nice library for this:

http://uniformjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

The following code does two things: 1. replaces the radio buttons on load.  2. Changes them when the images are clicked.  I'm not going to garuntee that it is perfect for your situation, but it should be enough to get you started.

```
// on load
$(function() {
    // replace the checkboxes with the images
    $("input name='answeroption']").each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) { // radio button is checked onload
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).after($("<img src='button_on.jpg' class='radioButtonImage' />"));
        } else { // radio button is not checked
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).after($("<img src='button_off.jpg'  class='radioButtonImage' />"));
        }
    });

    // setup click events to change the images
    $("input.radioButtonImage").click(function() {
        if($(this).attr('src') == 'button_on.jpg') { // its checked, so uncheck it
            $(this).attr('src', 'button_off.jpg');
            $(this).prev().attr('checked', 'false');
        } else { // its not checked, so check it
            $(this).attr('src', 'button_on.jpg');
            $(this).prev().attr('checked', 'true');
        }
    });
});
```