# How do I make a customized Radio Button using CSS and Javascript or DOJO?

Tags: javascript, css, html, dojo

My assignment-target image is in:

Link: http://i46.tinypic.com/w1uqza.png

I need to add a background gradient an inner circle onclick. I'm a beginner at this so any kind of help or direction in this would be very helpful.

Comment: How about using JQuery? A quick search on stackoverflow gave me: http://uniformjs.com/ EDIT: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114166/replacing-radio-buttons-with-different-images

Comment: I'm doing just a part of the website. I would prefer working with DOJO or Plain JavaScript, since rest of the site uses DOJO.

Comment: And is it OK to use CSS3? You wouldn't need Javascript at all: http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/custom-crossbrowser-styling-for-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can use jqtransform jquery for it.

http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/

Comment: -1 question is not tagged jquery amg, even title asks for the dojo solution

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new element with the backgroud, and click to change the value of real inputs.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .refRadio
        {
            height:30px;
            width:35px;
            background-image:url(http://i46.tinypic.com/w1uqza.png);
            background-position:-8px center;
            display:inline-block;
            vertical-align:middle;
        }
        .refRadio.checked
        {
            background-position:76px center;
        }
        input.refRadio
        {
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style=" line-height:40px; " >
        <input type="radio" class="refRadio" name="name" value="Yes" /> Yes 
        <input type="radio" class="refRadio" name="name" value="No" /> No
        <input type="radio" class="refRadio" name="name" value="No" /> No
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setupRadios() {
            var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                if (inputs[i].className != "refRadio")
                    continue;
                var input = inputs[i];
                var parent = input.parentNode;
                var newInput = document.createElement("span");
                newInput.setAttribute("class", "refRadio");
                newInput.setAttribute("data-value", input.value);
                newInput.input = input;
                input.newInput = newInput;
                input.changed = function () {
                    if(!this.newInput)
                        return;
                    if (this.checked)
                        this.newInput.className = "refRadio checked";
                    else
                        this.newInput.className = "refRadio";
                }
                parent.insertBefore(newInput, input);
                function click() {
                    this.input.checked = true;
                    this.className = "refRadio checked";

                    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                        var input = inputs[i];
                        input.changed.apply(input);
                    }
                }
                newInput.onclick = click;
            }
        }
        setupRadios();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Out-the-box sample from dojo explorer for radio's, using dijit.form.RadioButton:
[Live sample](http://dojocampus.org/explorer/#Dijit_Form%20Controls_RadioButton_Basic)

```
<p>
  <span>Radio group #1:</span>
  <input dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton" type="radio" name="g1" id="g1rb1" value="news">
  <label for="g1rb1">news</label>
  <input dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton" type="radio" name="g1" id="g1rb2" value="talk"
       checked="checked"/>
  <label for="g1rb2">talk</label>
  <input dojoType="dijit.form.RadioButton" type="radio" name="g1" id="g1rb3" value="weather"
       disabled="disabled"/>
  <label for="g1rb3">weather</label>
</p>
```

Nihilo sprites (imagegry) for radio's is [here](http://dojocampus.org/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/nihilo/images/spriteRadio.gif)
And it is using these selectors to do styling:

```
/* standard */
.nihilo .dijitRadio, .nihilo .dijitToggleButton .dijitRadioIcon {
background-position: -16px;
}
/* if checked */
.nihilo .dijitRadioChecked, .nihilo .dijitToggleButtonChecked .dijitRadioIcon {
background-position: 0px;
}
/* if disabled */
.nihilo .dijitRadioDisabled {
background-position: -32px;
}
.nihilo .dijitRadio, .nihilo .dijitRadioIcon {
background-image: url(images/spriteRadio.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```